# Sort a List inside List object

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

We had a scenario where we had to sort a object based on name and also the List Object inside that based on name. Please find the below Java objects.

Make class

```
class Make implements comparable<Make> {
    String name;
    List<Model> models;
    ....
    getter..
    setters..

    @Override
    public intcompareTo(object o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

Model Class

```
class Model implements comparable<Model> {
    String name ;
    ....
    getter..
    setters..

    @Override
    public intcompareTo(object o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Make> make = new ArrayList<Make>();
        Make make1 = new Make();
        make1.addName("B");

        Model model1 = new Model()
        model1.setName ("B");
        make1.addModel(model1);

        Model model2 = new Model()
        model2.setName ("A");
        make1.addModel(model2);

        make.add(make1);

        // This will sort the make Object but not the model. 
        collections.sort(make);
    }
}
```

We wanted to sort both Make and Model on Name.
How to sort both the make Models in the above scenario.?

Comment: You won't be able to with one call to `Collections.sort` -- you'll have to get each member list and sort them individually.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each Make object element and sort it's List field

```
for(Make makeElement : make)
{
    Collections.sort(makeElement.models);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with @James solution.

but if you really really want to sort everything with one call (**NOTE** internally is many many calls :) )

change `Make.intcompareTo(object 0)` to :

```
public intcompareTo(object 0)
{
  if(models!=null){
    Collection.sort(models);
  }
  return name.compareTo(o.name);
}
```

Comment: Sorting each time `compareTo` is invoked, does not only imply unnecessary sort operations in the case of a bigger outer list. In the actual example of the question, where the outer list has size *one*,  `compareTo` will never get invoked.